# hive column name alter without loosing data in portitioned avro table

Tags: hive, hql, alter

i have a avro hive table partitioned by date.

```
acct_no <string> acct_cd <int>  date <date>
acct01           01             2022-10-31
acct02           02             2022-10-31 
acct03           03             2022-10-31
```

i want to rename acct_cd to account_code

i used command

```
alter table <table_name> change acct_cd account_code int;
```

it changed the table attribute but data lost:

```
acct_no <string> account_code <int>  date <date>
acct01         null                  2022-10-31
acct02         null                  2022-10-31 
acct03         null                  2022-10-31
```

How to avoid losing data and change the column name?

Answer (score 0):

As per hive, [hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ChangeColumnName/Type/Position/Comment), `change` a column name just changes hive metadata, underlying data/structure remains as is. Which means, you have to take care of the data after alter.

You have two options -

1. Create a backup table. Drop original table. Crete a new table with new column name and insert into the new table from backup table.
2. Create a backup table. Rename the column in  original table. Use `insert overwrite table` command to fillup original table from backup table.